# SQL add a new column and its values only can be in several fixed options

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to add a new column with SQL in my data table as below,

```
CREATE TABLE brands (
    Brand varchar(255),
    Contact varchar(150),
    Address varchar(255),
    Location varchar(50),
)
```

:
[image]

I wish to add a new column called country, and the value only can be selected from the following values: "Japan", "New Zealand", "US", "France"
[image]

I can add the new column but I don't know how to set the limited optional values for the column. Please help if you have ideas. Many thanks

Comment: You could use a `check constraint` with an `IN` statement with the allowed values. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-check-constraints?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a check constraint, or a foreign key.

Check constraint:

```
alter table brands add country_name varchar(64) not null;
alter table brands add constraint ck_country_list 
   check (country_name in ('Japan', 'New Zealand', 'US', 'France'));
```

With a check constraint, the values that are allowed never change (unless you change the constraint code). With a foreign key, the allowed values are stored in another table. As long as the value exists in the other table, they are allowed in this table.

```
create table countries(country_name varchar(64) not null primary key);

insert countries (country_name) 
values ('France'), ('New Zealand') -- etc

alter table brands add country_name varchar(64) not null;

alter table brands add constraint fk_brands_countries 
   foreign key (country_name) references countries (country_name);
```

But we can actually do even better that! Countries already have a well defined "thing" which uniquely identifies them: [ISO3166 country codes](https://www.iso.org/iso-3166-country-codes.html). You can use the 2 char, 3 char, or int versions. Using well defined standards where you can is always a good idea for primary keys.

This is the next level up beyond what you are currently trying to learn. But here's what it might look like:

```
create table countries
(
   country_code char(2) not null primary key clustered,
   country_name varchar(64) not null
);

insert countries (country_code, country_name)
values ('FR', 'France'), ('NZ', 'New Zealand') -- etc etc;

alter table brands add country_code char(2) not null;

alter table brands add constraint fk_brands_countries
   foreign key (country_code) references countries (country_code);
```

When you want to get the country name, you join the `brands` table to the `countries` table using the `country_code` column.

Answer (score 2):

After you added the column you could add a check constraint

```
ALTER TABLE brands
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_country check (Country IN ('Japan', 'New Zealand', 'US', 'France'));
```